# partially initialized module 'turtle' has no attribute 'forward' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, python-turtle

My code

```
import turtle 
turtle.forward(15)
```

It shows the error : **partially initialized module 'turtle' has no attribute 'forward' (most likely due to a circular import)**

Comment: I did not get this.

Comment: Oh yeah I savved my file by *`turtle.py`*

Comment: Are you using the built in turtle?

Answer (score 2):

> Oh yeah I savved my file by turtle.py

<sup>*-- [comment by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67714801/#comment119689828_67714801)*</sup>

Don't do that!  Your code will not import the Python turtle.py library but rather assume your code *is* that library.  And all the functions and methods, like `forward()` will be missing.

Answer (score 1):

[Edit: I misinterpreted the problem. The answer below was given on the assumption that the turtle-library only works in an object oriented way.]

The problem with your code is that you to not create an instance of the turtle class before using is.
Importing a library with "import turtle" basically only is like telling you program that a library with that name exists. To use the functionality of the imported library, you first have to generate a turtle-object (which you can also name turtle, but I'm using my_turtle to clarify the difference).

```
import turtle
my_turtle = turtle.Turtle
my_turtle.forward(20)
```

So you import the turtle library, which contains a class named Turtle, and with "my_turtle = turtle.Turtle", you create an instance of that class, which **is** a Turtle.
Mind that you also have to set a screen on which your turtle draws, using

```
screen = turtle.Screen
screen.exitonclick()
```

Additionally, you should refer to the documentation of the turtle library.
Turtle is very well documented in a way that even new programmers can easily learn the basic concepts by reading the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html

Comment: The premise of your answer is incorrect.  The OP's code *as written* is a valid turtle program.  It will open a window, move a turtle forward 15 pixels, and then, depending on the environment, close the window or leave it open.  Turtle has *both* functional and object-oriented interfaces.  This is the functional one.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the clarification, I clearly missed that. I will edit my answer accordingly.